# Как сделать так, чтобы Jpanel, помещенная в JFrame, автоматически занимала все доступное в JFrame пространство в Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Пытаюсь создать самое простое приложение. Но, при добавлении компонента `JPanel` в `JFrame`, `JPanel` не занимает все допустимое пространство. Программа выдает следующий результат: `"java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]"`, то есть размеры `JPanel` нулевые. 
Как сделать так, чтобы `Jpanel`, помещенная в `JFrame`, автоматически занимала все доступное в `JFrame` пространство в `Java`? И можно было бы сразу узнать эти размеры?

Листинг программы:

```
public class Test1 extends JFrame{
    Test1() {
        super("Графическое приложение");
        setBounds(50,50,1000, 450);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        this.add(panel);
        System.out.println(this.getComponent(0).getSize());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       new Test1();
    }
}
```

Comment: оно само растянется, когда фрейм станет видимым (там по-умолчанию используется `BorderLayout`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам правильно подсказали в комментарии (пользователь [zRrr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190934/zrrr)), попробуйте "запустить" следующий код:

```
public class Test1 extends JFrame{       
        Test1 () {
            super("Графическое приложение");
            setBounds(50,50,1000, 450);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            this.setContentPane(panel);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
           Test1 test = new Test1();
           test.setVisible(true);
           System.out.println(test.getContentPane().getSize());
        }

    }
```